# Capture dynamic value from jmeter request body and correlate back in the same

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Working on the Jmeter to create load script for an inbound call. When the application receives the call Jmeter captured the below as POST request body:

```
5|0|21|https://d50.eng.domain.com:1050/newgenmashup/v1/mashup/|1D4E8B05B21570719C10066C4E15360C|com.contactual.client.SFService|triggerEvent|java.lang.String|com.contactual.client.model.GenericXmlData|java.util.TreeMap|tenant~~pagent2|com.contactual.client.model.GenericXmlData/2918165779||353-726-6515|no|offered|PHONE|in|563|PavanInboundQueue|1|465|<UserData>
<param name = "@pri"><![CDATA[100]]></param>
<param name="callingName"><![CDATA[ 1234567366]]></param>
<param name="cha"><![CDATA[3537266515]]></param>
<param name="channelName"><![CDATA[353-726-6515]]></param>
<param name="cnt"><![CDATA[0]]></param>
<param name="con"><![CDATA[0]]></param>
<param name="med"><![CDATA[T]]></param>
<param name="otim"><![CDATA[1550070210]]></param>
<param name="pho"><![CDATA[ 1234567366]]></param>
<param name="phoneNum"><![CDATA[ 1234567366]]></param>
<param name="priority"><![CDATA[50]]></param>
<param name="que"><![CDATA[vcclondon~~queue~~phone~~563]]></param>
<param name="queueDirection"><![CDATA[in]]></param>
<param name="tenantName"><![CDATA[vcclondon]]></param>
<param name="tenantRecServer"><![CDATA[d50]]></param>
<param name="tenantSkillName"><![CDATA[PavanInboundQueue]]></param>
<param name="tim"><![CDATA[1550070210]]></param>
<param name="tok"><![CDATA[465]]></param>
<param name="queuedTime"><![CDATA[0]]></param>
<param name="ani"><![CDATA[ 1234567366]]></param>
<param name="interaction_guid"><![CDATA[int-168e76257e3-r5tEbRqwNR7hBd7jmuvwnsxG9-phone-00-vcclondon]]></param>
<param name="transaction_id"><![CDATA[465]]></param>
<param name="notes"><![CDATA[]]></param>
<param name="callbackTimeMs"><![CDATA[]]></param>
<param name="ctl_userdata"><![CDATA[[doNotCallSelected\!false][donotcallSelected\!false]]]></param>
</UserData>|java.util.TreeMap/1575826026|1|2|3|4|3|5|6|7|8|9|0|0|0|0|10|0|0|0|10|0|11|0|12|0|13|10|0|10|1|0|0|0|14|15|16|17|18|10|10|0|19|20|21|0|0|
```

I would like to retrieve each param value and correlate. Stored above body data into string.

```
String requestBody = sampler.getArguments();
```

Used the xmlslurper to navigate to treemap. Example: I am trying to extract the interaction id using below snippet.

```
def UserData = new XmlSlurper().parseText(requestBody)
def interaction_guid = UserData.param[20].@name
```

Expected: I would like to correlate all values. Because, no value is user input data.

Actual is:

```
2019-02-18 12:14:33,111 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:935) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:537) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:?]
at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:205) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:258) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parseText(XmlSlurper.java:284) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
at groovy.util.XmlSlurper$parseText.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
at Script26.run(Script26.groovy:17) ~[?:?]
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
... 9 more
```

Can you please help me in extracting each param, correlate and put back in the in the same POST request.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your way of getting request payload is wrong, you should amend this line:

   ```
   String requestBody = sampler.getArguments();
   ```

   to this one

   ```
   String requestBody  = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
   ```

   as [Sampler.getArguments() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getArguments--) returns [Arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html) class instance and you need the value of the first one.
2. Your request body doesn't seem to be a valid XML therefore you won't be able to go for XmlSlurper, consider using [Find Operator instead](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_find_operator)

   ```
   def interaction_guid= (requestBody =~ "<param name=\"interaction_guid\"><!\\[CDATA\\[(.+?)\\]\\]></param>")[0][1] as String
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

   Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Here is more clarification: These are the params i am having in current request body but not previous request's response. Can we make these parameters are dynamic and pass in the current request? If yes, please provide some example for my query. Thank you.